# Servlet.service() in Spring-mvc is throwing StackOverflowError

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, servlets

I am doing one simple Login Application using Spring MVC .
It is a MAVEN Dynamic Web project .
While running the project I am getting **StackOverFlowError** from **Servlet.service()** method .
I have all file structure like below .

Web.xml :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
version="3.0">
<display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>CPIHomepage.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring-mvc</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <!--  <servlet-class>com.icesoft.faces.webapp.xmlhttp.PersistentFacesServlet</servlet-class> -->
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring-mvc</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

User-Beans.xml :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation=" http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
<context:component-scan base-package="com.ericsson.oss.wmom" />
<context:annotation-config />
<bean id="loginBean" class="com.ericsson.oss.wmom.Bean.LoginBean" />
<bean id="loginController" class="com.ericsson.oss.wmom.Controller.LoginController" />
```

Spring-mvc-servlet.xml :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation=" http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
<import resource="classpath:user-beans.xml" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.ericsson.oss.wmom" />
<context:annotation-config />
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/" />
    <property name="suffix" value="." />
</bean>
```

Pom.xml :-

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.oss.ericsson.wranmom</groupId>
<artifactId>CPITool</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>CPITool Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <spring.version>4.3.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <junit.version>3.8.1</junit.version>
    <servlet.version>3.1.0</servlet.version>
    <servlet.version>3.0.1</servlet.version>

</properties>
<dependencies>
    <!-- javax.servlet-api dependancy configures javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet 
        class in the java build path of index.jsp to avoid the below error . "The 
        superclass \u201cjavax.servlet.http.HttpServlet\u201d was not found on the Java Build 
        Path index.jsp" -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>${servlet.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring Framework -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Servlet API -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>${servlet.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.faces/javax.faces-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.faces-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.faces/jsf-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>CPITool</finalName>
</build>
```

Exception which I am getting :-

```
 Servlet.service() for servlet spring-mvc threw exception
java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.net.SocketImpl.getInetAddress(SocketImpl.java:235)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.getInetAddress(SocksSocketImpl.java:1038)
at java.net.Socket.getInetAddress(Socket.java:675)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.action(Http11Processor.java:1055)
at org.apache.coyote.Request.action(Request.java:351)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getRemoteAddr(Request.java:1235)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getRemoteAddr(RequestFacade.java:481)
at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getRemoteAddr(ServletRequestWrapper.java:260)
at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getRemoteAddr(ServletRequestWrapper.java:260)
at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getRemoteAddr(ServletRequestWrapper.java:260)
at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getRemoteAddr(ServletRequestWrapper.java:260)
at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getRemoteAddr(ServletRequestWrapper.java:260)
at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getRemoteAddr(ServletRequestWrapper.java:260)
at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getRemoteAddr(ServletRequestWrapper.java:260)
at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getRemoteAddr(ServletRequestWrapper.java:260)
at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getRemoteAddr(ServletRequestWrapper.java:260)
at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getRemoteAddr(ServletRequestWrapper.java:260)
at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getRemoteAddr(ServletRequestWrapper.java:260)
at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getRemoteAddr(ServletRequestWrapper.java:260)
at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getRemoteAddr(ServletRequestWrapper.java:260)
at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getRemoteAddr(ServletRequestWrapper.java:260)
at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getRemoteAddr(ServletRequestWrapper.java:260)
at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getRemoteAddr(ServletRequestWrapper.java:260)
at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getRemoteAddr(ServletRequestWrapper.java:260)
at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getRemoteAddr(ServletRequestWrapper.java:260)
at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getRemoteAddr(ServletRequestWrapper.java:260)
at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getRemoteAddr(ServletRequestWrapper.java:260)
at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getRemoteAddr(ServletRequestWrapper.java:260)
at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getRemoteAddr(ServletRequestWrapper.java:260)
at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getRemoteAddr(ServletRequestWrapper.java:260)
at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getRemoteAddr(ServletRequestWrapper.java:260)
at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getRemoteAddr(ServletRequestWrapper.java:260)
at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getRemoteAddr(ServletRequestWrapper.java:260)
at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getRemoteAddr(ServletRequestWrapper.java:260)
at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getRemoteAddr(ServletRequestWrapper.java:260)
at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getRemoteAddr(ServletRequestWrapper.java:260)
at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getRemoteAddr(ServletRequestWrapper.java:260)
at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getRemoteAddr(ServletRequestWrapper.java:260)
at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getRemoteAddr(ServletRequestWrapper.java:260)
at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getRemoteAddr(ServletRequestWrapper.java:260)
at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getRemoteAddr(ServletRequestWrapper.java:260)
at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getRemoteAddr(ServletRequestWrapper.java:260)
at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getRemoteAddr(ServletRequestWrapper.java:260)
at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getRemoteAddr(ServletRequestWrapper.java:260)
at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getRemoteAddr(ServletRequestWrapper.java:260)
at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getRemoteAddr(ServletRequestWrapper.java:260)
at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getRemoteAddr(ServletRequestWrapper.java:260)
at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getRemoteAddr(ServletRequestWrapper.java:260)
at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getRemoteAddr(ServletRequestWrapper.java:260)
at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getRemoteAddr(ServletRequestWrapper.java:260)
at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getRemoteAddr(ServletRequestWrapper.java:260)
at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getRemoteAddr(ServletRequestWrapper.java:260)
at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getRemoteAddr(ServletRequestWrapper.java:260)
at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getRemoteAddr(ServletRequestWrapper.java:260)
at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getRemoteAddr(ServletRequestWrapper.java:260)
at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getRemoteAddr(ServletRequestWrapper.java:260)
at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getRemoteAddr(ServletRequestWrapper.java:260)
at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getRemoteAddr(ServletRequestWrapper.java:260)
at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getRemoteAddr(ServletRequestWrapper.java:260)
at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getRemoteAddr(ServletRequestWrapper.java:260)
at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getRemoteAddr(ServletRequestWrapper.java:260)
at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getRemoteAddr(ServletRequestWrapper.java:260)
at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getRemoteAddr(ServletRequestWrapper.java:260)
at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getRemoteAddr(ServletRequestWrapper.java:260)
at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getRemoteAddr(ServletRequestWrapper.java:260)
at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getRemoteAddr(ServletRequestWrapper.java:260)
at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getRemoteAddr(ServletRequestWrapper.java:260)
at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getRemoteAddr(ServletRequestWrapper.java:260)
at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getRemoteAddr(ServletRequestWrapper.java:260)
at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getRemoteAddr(ServletRequestWrapper.java:260)
at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getRemoteAddr(ServletRequestWrapper.java:260)
at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getRemoteAddr(ServletRequestWrapper.java:260)
at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getRemoteAddr(ServletRequestWrapper.java:260)
at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getRemoteAddr(ServletRequestWrapper.java:260)
at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getRemoteAddr(ServletRequestWrapper.java:260)
at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getRemoteAddr(ServletRequestWrapper.java:260)
at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getRemoteAddr(ServletRequestWrapper.java:260)
at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getRemoteAddr(ServletRequestWrapper.java:260)
at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getRemoteAddr(ServletRequestWrapper.java:260)
at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getRemoteAddr(ServletRequestWrapper.java:260)
at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getRemoteAddr(ServletRequestWrapper.java:260)
```

LoginController.java :-

```
  @Controller
 public class LoginController {
  @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public ModelAndView showLogin(HttpServletRequest request,     HttpServletResponse response) {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("login");
    mav.addObject("login", new LoginBean());
    return mav;
  }

  @RequestMapping(value = "/loginProcess", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public ModelAndView loginProcess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
  @ModelAttribute("login") LoginBean login) {
    ModelAndView mav = null;
    try {
        /*
         * Will add the logic for validate User later 
         */
        //User user = userService.validateUser(login);
        if (null != login) {
            mav = new ModelAndView("welcome");
            mav.addObject("<i>Happy to see you </i>",login.getXid());
            } else {
            mav = new ModelAndView("login");
            mav.addObject("message", "Please check.. Xid or Password may be wrong !!!");
            }
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return mav;
  }
```

}

Comment: Tried some ways ..But it did not help me out .

Comment: Please remove duplicate dependencies from your pom file, sometimes it causes issue

Comment: I commented the duplicate entries in pom.xml and run the project .But facing same issue again .

Comment: something is causing infinite recursions. is this the full stack trace.

Comment: Yes this is the full stack trace .Basically what is happening when I am clicking on login option in home page , this Error is coming .

Comment: show your login controller code as well

Comment: Added LoginController.java in description

Comment: Can Anyone help here